# How to download a pdf file on server from other server php

Tags: php, cakephp, pdf

I am stuck in a situation where I have to download a `pdf` file from an absolute path to our server but I am unable to do so. All process working in background and I don't want that front user can see what will happen in background.

Can anyone provide any solution? May be it is so simple but I am stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Copy](http://php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php)

```
$pdf = "http://wwww.somesite.com/something.pdf";
$pdf = str_replace(" ", "%20", $pdf);
$savedpdf = "/rootsomething/savedpdf/saved.pdf";
if(copy($pdf, $savedpdf)){
//The file was copied correctly 
}
```

Comment: If you don't mind, can you post the url you are trying to save the PDF from?

Comment: It might be because you have a space in the url. See the updated code above.

Answer (score 0):

Use some HTTP client library like [PHP CURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php)

Comment: could it is possible with curl? if yes can you provide a solution example?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use `PHP CURL` but it will block until you receive file from the external resource.Not a good option if file is bit heavier.
You may want to run your script as a `cronjob` in that scenario or use some multi-threaded library like [multirequest](http://code.google.com/p/multirequest/)

Here is bare-bone code snippet to make a http request.I have not tested it but you can get some insight and tweak/debug it yourself.

```
    function saveCompleteRequestToFile(MultiRequest_Request $request, MultiRequest_Handler $handler) {
    $filename = preg_replace('/[^\w\.]/', '', $request->getUrl());
    file_put_contents('directory_path_here' . $filename, $request->getContent());
}

$mrHandler = new MultiRequest_Handler();
$mrHandler->onRequestComplete('saveCompleteRequestToFile');

$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'Accept: text/xml,application/xml,application/xhtml+xml,text/html;q=0.9,text/plain;q=0.8,image/png,*/*;q=0.5';
$headers[] = 'Cache-Control: no-cache';
$headers[] = 'Connection: Keep-Alive';
$headers[] = 'Keep-Alive: 300';
$headers[] = 'Accept-Charset: UTF-8,Windows-1251,ISO-8859-1;q=0.7,*;q=0.7';
$headers[] = 'Accept-Language: ru,en-us,en;q=0.5';
$headers[] = 'Pragma:';
$mrHandler->requestsDefaults()->addHeaders($headers);

$options = array();
$options[CURLOPT_USERAGENT] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2.12) Gecko/20101026 Firefox/3.6.12';
$mrHandler->requestsDefaults()->addCurlOptions($options);

$request = new MultiRequest_Request('http://somedomain/path/file.pdf');
$mrHandler->pushRequestToQueue($request);
$mrHandler->start();
```

Comment: with curl how can i achieve it please explain?